# Prove whether x^{2/3} is locally Lipschitz or not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, upper-lower-bounds

Let $f$ be the function defined as follows:

$$f:(t,x)\in R \times R \rightarrow f(t,x)= x^{\frac{2}{3}} \in R$$

I want to know whether $f$ is locally Lipschitz with respect to the variable $x$. Problem comes when studying the points $(t,0): t\in R$, because we cannot use the continuity of partial derivative with respect $x$ as it is not defined in those points. Thus, for a given neighbourhood of $(t,0)$, denoted by $U$, and $(t,x),(t,y) \in U$, I would like to prove whether the quotient:

$$\frac{|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|}{|x-y|} = \frac{|x^{\frac{2}{3}}-y^{\frac{2}{3}}|}{|x-y|}$$

is bounded or not. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it differentiable somewhere? Think of the mean value theorem, which relates the quotient you wish to study with the derivative value at some point.

Comment: The partial derivative is not bounded in a neighboorhood of $(t,0)$, so I don't think it can be useful. @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг

Comment: The partial derivative is not bounded  near $(t,0)$ : but you could still use it in points where it's really high, to show non-Lipschitzness, right? For the Lipschitz ratio grows very high if points are near $(t,0)$ by MVT, right?

Comment: Or just plug in $y = 0$ and the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: Thanks @Adayah, definitely the answer I was looking for